# CMake c++ library linking

Tags: c++, cmake

I have Fortran target in CMake which relies on C++ libraries.  What is *portable* way to include STDC++ into linking?

Answer (score 1):

If you're linking with gfortran, add `-lstdc++`, if linking with g++, you'll need `-lgfortran`. Either way, you'll need both of them, it's just that g++ automagically links with libstdc++, and gfortran automagically links with libgfortran.

There is no "portable" way as in cross-compiler or cross-"standard library vendor", because all the libraries are named differently.

Answer (score 0):

Theoretically the STL is part of the C++, so you don't need to do anything in CMake to use STL. On other hand: if your C++ libraries have dependencies and their have CMake module (e.g.: FintQt4), CMake automatically handle the linking process.

Comment: The linker is not c++, rather fortran.